# Can I redirect or proxy **/ to **/index.html along side a proxy_pass'd route?

Tags: nginx

I have the following domain pointed to my nginx `my.web.server`

I'd like to proxy requests to `/cdn` to a filehost located on `file.host/myfiles`

The config file reads as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.web.server;

    location ^~ /cdn {      
        proxy_pass https://file.host/myfiles;
    }
}
```

This configuration successfully proxies all requests coming in to the destination file host, however I get no redirects to `index.html` should a / or  route be entered.

An example of what I'd like to achieve is here:

```
my.web.server/cdn           => (proxy) file.host/myfiles/index.html
my.web.server/cdn/          => (proxy) file.host/myfiles/index.html
my.web.server/cdn/images    => (proxy) file.host/myfiles/images/index.html
my.web.server/cdn/images/   => (proxy) file.host/myfiles/images/index.html

my.web.server/cdn/**        => (proxy) file.host/myfiles/**/index.html
my.web.server/cdn/**/       => (proxy) file.host/myfiles/**/index.html
```

Ideally, you wouldn't see the index.html in the url and it would simply proxy to that file path, however if that's not possible, redirecting the user there would also be fine.

---

I have been trying things like:

```
location ^~ /cdn {      
    proxy_pass https://file.host/myfiles;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html;
}
```

What I am hoping to achieve with this is telling nginx to "proxy here", try to see if there is a file and if nothing appears, try to find an `index.html` in that route.

Comment: `try_files` tests for the presence of a local file. You need to handle a 404 response and redirect appropriately. Maybe something horrible like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19667997/4862445) will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) docs:

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a
>   request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
>   matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive

Thus:

1. You request URI is being [normalized](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)
2. The part of its normalized counterpart matching your location `/cdn` is replaced by `/myfiles`

Remember normalization removes artifacts like directory traversals, thus requesting `/cdn/**` will most probably result in a normalized path `/`.

If you want to avoid normalization, you will have to interfere with normal match. You could try (untested):

```
location ^~ /cdn {
    rewrite    /cdn(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass https://file.host/myfiles;
}
```